# How can I access my list from another python module with my voice?

Tags: python, list, voice-recognition, voice, assistant

I am trying to build a voice assistant using python. But I have some problems with it.

I have a assistantInputs.py file which is contains words, and main.py which is main program.

Here's my code in assistantInputs.py:

```
hello = ["hi","hey","hello","greetings"]
```

Here's my code in main.py :

```
import assistantInputs as aI

if voice_data in aI.hello:
    print("Hey!")
```

'voice_data' allows me to speak and recognize my voice.

But it is not working. What am I supposed to do? I can't access `hello` list.

Comment: What is the variable `voice_data`?  What happens when you print the `hello` list?

Comment: `voice_data` is variable that computer understands what I say.

i'm trying to speak like "hi" or "hey", for this code it should print "Hey!" to console, but it's not working. nothing happens. it just prints a blank to console. i guess there's a problem with if statement.

Comment: Print the `voice_data` object, see if it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: it just prints a blank again. nothing happens. what should I try?